# What could have caused automount to try to mount this nonexistent directory?

Tags: automounting, syslog

In /var/log/messages I found entries like this

```
Oct 18 2:10:15 linux automount[946]: attempting to mount entry /home/randomusername
Oct 18 2:10:15 linux automount[946]: key "randomusername" not found in map source(s).
Oct 18 2:10:15 linux automount[946]: failed to mount /home/randomusername
```

I can't find any files in /etc with randomusername. I can cause the same messages to be generated if I try to cd into that nonexistent directory, but I'm sure that I didn't do that, and even though this server is in a mult-user environment, I'm also pretty sure that no one else was logged in when this happened. If I cd into a directory under /home that exists then it automounts without error.

What are some other things that could have caused this?

Comment: I think it is `autofs`.

Comment: I know it's autofs, but the question is why is it trying to mount those random directories?